# centering (horizontally and vertically) <ul> in navbr div

Tags: html, html-lists, centering

I know this has been addressed previously, but for the life of me I can't get it to work with my code (yes, I'm new to this so please be gentle, and do let me know if I am going against SO etiquette!).

Basically, trying to setup a `navbar` with links centered vertically that become highlighted when hovered over.
I got it setup by eyeballing it and adjusting the `margins` / `padding`, but surely there is a better way to to go about this.

Also, how do I go about centering the links horizontally as well?

Here's the relevant code.
http://jsbin.com/wekuqidu/1/

Thanks all!!!!

Comment: Might be easier to put the `ul` in an element you would reposition and reposition that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using line-height, you can also try using table-cell to vertically align in the middle

http://jsbin.com/nagoposu/2/

Comment: This worked great, thanks Timur!! Followup question: if I set font-weight to bold for #navbar a:hover, I noticed that everything right to the hovered link shifts slightly to the right; What is causing that and how do I address it?

Comment: thants because the elemnt is getting wider, if you add some width to #navbar a it would not move http://jsbin.com/nagoposu/3/